# Is it possible to concurrently read from RocksDB?

Tags: database, database-design, concurrency, synchronization, rocksdb

I have the case where multiple Linux processes need to link with RocksDB library and concurently read (high load) the same database.
The only one process updates database several times a day.

Is it possible to concurrently read from within multiple processes from RocksDB?
Unfortunately can't find this information over the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that [Rocksdb supports](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Read-only-and-Secondary-instances) multiple read-only or secondary instances (two variations of read-only mode):

> Read-only Instance - Opens the database in read-only mode. When the Read-only instance is created, it gets a static read-only view of
> the Primary Instance’s database contents

> Secondary Instance – Opens the database in read-only mode. Supports extra ability to dynamically catch-up with the Primary
> instance (through a manual call by the user – based on their
> delay/frequency requirements)

But only one read-write instance:

> The Primary Instance is a regular RocksDB instance capable of read,
> write, flush and compaction. The Read-only and Secondary Instances
> supports read operations alone.
>
> Only single instance of Primary is allowed; but many concurrent
> Read-only and Secondary Instances are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Basic-Operations#concurrency indicates that:

> A database may only be opened by one process at a time. The rocksdb
> implementation acquires a lock from the operating system to prevent
> misuse. Within a single process, the same rocksdb::DB object may be
> safely shared by multiple concurrent threads. I.e., different threads
> may write into or fetch iterators or call Get on the same database
> without any external synchronization (the rocksdb implementation will
> automatically do the required synchronization).

Comment: Seems that there is some inconsistency in Rocksdb documentation..